# WPF. C#. Как узнать, какой элемент выделен в ListBox, если список стилизован?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть список

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxFolder" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClientsOnlineList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,50,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="301" Background="#FFD0E6C5" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="SelectClient"></EventSetter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>Bold"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="23"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}"  /> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

ClientsOnlineList - Список. Содержит поля UserName, id и т.д.

Как мне при выделении списка- узнать- какой именно ClientsOnlineList.Id был выделен? Так как список стилизованный- я потерялся в связях и как узнать выделенный элемент?

Answer (score 3):

Создайте свойство (тип вы сами знаете) CurrentClient и привяжете его к `SelectedItem` выбор в ListBox будет доступен через это свойство.

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Это коллекция для заполнения ListBox
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<Animal> _Animals;
    public ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals
    {
        get { return _Animals; }
        set
        {
            if (_Animals == value) return;
            _Animals = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Animals)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Текущее выбранное животное в ListBox
    /// </summary>
    private Animal _CurrentAnimal;
    public Animal CurrentAnimal
    {
        get { return _CurrentAnimal; }
        set
        {
            if (_CurrentAnimal == value) return;
            _CurrentAnimal = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentAnimal)));
         }
    }
```

В XAML

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Animals, Mode=TwoWay}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentAnimal}"/>
```

Comment: А можете по подробнее написать?

Comment: Изменил ответ. Полный пример можете [скачать](https://yadi.sk/d/ud7mV3Fbwqr6G)

Answer (score 1):

Все просто. Вот Handler для Вашего EventSetter:

```
private void SelectClient(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = listboxFolder.Items.IndexOf(((ListBoxItem)sender).DataContext);
        MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
    }
```

Он вернет положение элемента относительно самого листа. В принципе - это тот же listboxFolder.SelectedIndex, но его можно оптимизировать под себя.

Но так как Вам необходим id, используйте следующий код:

```
listboxFolder.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) => {
    var id = (listboxFolder.SelectedItem as [Ваш класс клиента]).id;
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
};
```

И не к чему писать лишний код в модели данных.

Comment: Автор вопроса использует байдинг (это видно из разметки XAML), т.е. работает в парадигме шаблона MVVM. А ваш пример из простого подхода работы с обработчиками событий в кодбихайнд, что ни есть гуд.

Comment: @Bulson, это одно из решений.

Comment: @Bulson, а вот второе должно и Вам понравиться. Перечитайте мой ответ.

Comment: что мне должно понравится? В принципе, да так можно работать в небольшом учебном проекте, но не нужно в случае работы над  серьезным приложением.

Comment: Выше я давал ссылку на маленький проект-пример как работать с коллекциями в WPF, можете тоже скачать и посмотреть.